# Get the ok massage from http posrequest

Tags: c#

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "access_token": "ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIkhTMjU2IiwNCiAgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiDQp9.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.ixRDlLYfrJ-OQs6LzkLhf07skR9z1i-3w1u7rtRppgE",
  "expires_in": 1800.0,
  "refresh_token": "zcysqIg/npIN0YXnAJZKkBIA4DFuL+bBq1kOEamlBmtbxrHLWamVAVynK9vSGPEZgS5OAD7gpY2OoBSeaHH48aQ/ER3WZOnOijWQrxEFNKU="
}
```

This is what i have json response. i want to display acces_token from this.so i want code line. 
this is the code I try to get this json.

```
public async Task NewMethodAsync()
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient objClient = new HttpClient();

        Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://approvalbotbeta.azurewebsites.net/api/token");
        Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var client_ID = "ca647d7796c548209cdda9ed004c38aa5248171708028004628";
        var client_secret = "QXBwcm92YWxCb3RfVE9H7auiwc6RhE6ldS6WGsqWh2NhNjQ3ZDc3OTZjNTQ4MjA5Y2RkYTllZDAwNGMzOGFhNTI0ODE3MTcwODAyODAwNDYyOA==";
        pairs.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        pairs.Add("reply_url", "http://localhost");
        FormUrlEncodedContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
        var encordedString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(client_ID + ":" + client_secret));
        // httpContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encordedString);
        //httpContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encordedString);
        // httpContent.Headers.Add["Authorization"] = "Basic" + encordedString;

        objClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encordedString);

        HttpResponseMessage respon = await objClient.PostAsync("https://approvalbotbeta.azurewebsites.net/api/token", httpContent);
        if (respon.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Is that your _actual_ client id and secret?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) library and use this code:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
string token = json.refresh_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create response class

```
public class Response
{
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public double expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
}
```

Then use Newstonsoft Json - https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

```
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
    Console.WriteLine(response.access_token);
```